# Creación de modelo de datos Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema. He visto algunos videos, he probado mi conexión, carga el diagrama, pero salen esos errores.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que has intentado para evitar que cualquier persona te sugiera algo que ya hiciste. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, te invito a leer los siguientes enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> Aquí aprenderás el uso del sitio. Recomendaciones del mismo SOes para preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y mis recomendaciones en base a los años que llevo en el sitio: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.